# Collision detection to just add +1 once not several times the object collides

Tags: c#, xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="CatGame.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="640"  KeyDown="UserControl_KeyDown">
    <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="white">
    <Image Source="level1.jpg"></Image>
    <TextBlock FontSize="24" Canvas.Left="700" Canvas.Top="90" Name="score">/TextBlock>        
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>



if (DetectCollisionZero(myCat, myZero))
          {
           int scoreAsInt;
           if (Int32.TryParse(score.Text, out scoreAsInt) != null)
               {
                   scoreAsInt = scoreAsInt + 1;
                   score.Text = scoreAsInt.ToString();
               }
               LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(myZero);
             }

     public bool DetectCollisionZero(ContentControl myCat, ContentControl myZero)
             {

                 Rect myCatRect = new Rect(
                         new Point(Convert.ToDouble(myCat.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                              Convert.ToDouble(myCat.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                                      new Point((Convert.ToDouble(myCat.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + myCat.ActualWidth),
                                              (Convert.ToDouble(myCat.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + myCat.ActualHeight))
                              );

                 Rect myZeroRect = new Rect(
             new Point(Convert.ToDouble(myZero.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)),
                                             Convert.ToDouble(myZero.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty))),
                                     new Point((Convert.ToDouble(myZero.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)) + myZero.ActualWidth),
                                             (Convert.ToDouble(myZero.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)) + myZero.ActualHeight))
                             );

                 myCatRect.Intersect(myZeroRect);
                 return !(myCatRect == Rect.Empty);
             }
```

I basically have a cat colliding with an object (myZero) and when this happens my score should add +1 this kind of works however once the (myZero) is removed the user can still go over the location the object was and receive more points.

How can I make it so only 1 point will only ever be added.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in DetectCollisionLeft, which you didn't post code for.

Comment: no need to put "C# XAML" in the title. Just leave it in the tags.

Comment: Ouch! Painful code. Don't do `Convert.ToDouble(myCat.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty))`. Just do `Canvas.GetLeft(myCat)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect this to do anything different after you've removed `myZero` from the canvas? Your collision-detection method just reads the properties that determine `myZero`'s bounding box (properties that won't change just because you removed it from a collection), compare that to `myCat`'s bounding box, and decides whether they intersect. Nothing in `DetectCollisionZero` will behave differently based on whether `myZero` is still in the `LayoutRoot.Children` collection.

If you want it to do something different, you're going to have to write some code that checks for the condition you're interested in (`myZero` is no longer supposed to be present as part of the game board) and reacts appropriately (no longer returning `true` when checking for collisions).